# Changing volume of java application

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Im making a mp3 player with MP3SPI 1.9.5 (http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) i want to make a jSlider to change de volume of the application, but i dont have any idea how to do that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The article [Processing Audio With Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html) should get you started.

I've had most success using the MASTER_GAIN. But in the end I decided to go the "Manipulating Audio Directly" route.